# How to rename profile directory in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

I have renamed the account of a user in windows 7. How can I rename the profile directory to match the new user name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the procedure is identical to the one in Vista. You can try following the suggestions from this site: http://www.fixya.com/support/r463850-rename_or_move_user_profile_folder